# CaptureElement preview not available sometimes

Tags: windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I have problem with initialization camera on Windows Universal Apps. This code works and never throw any exception, but i have wrapped it into dialog control. Problem is sometimes (1/10 dialog openings) i don't see preview from camera. Have you any idea how to fix that or at least check if preview is displayed?

```
    private async Task InitCameraAsync()
    {
            var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
            var backCam = devices.FirstOrDefault(q => q.EnclosureLocation != null && q.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);

            var mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
            if (backCam != null)
            {
                await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings()
                {
                    VideoDeviceId = backCam.Id,
                    AudioDeviceId = String.Empty,
                    StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
                    PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview
                });
            }
            else
            {
                await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();
            }
            CameraControl.Source = mediaCapture;

            SetImageEncodingProperties(); // get encoding properties to save images
            await SetPreviewResolutionAsync();

            await CameraControl.Source.StartPreviewAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying that this code works 100% in a page, but fails every now and then when inside a dialog? And when you say dialog control, do you mean this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh738363.aspx ?

Comment: Dialog is my own full screen control which have "IsOpen" bool property. On changing value of this property, if value is true I initialize camera with code from snippet. If value is false, I disosed CameraControl.Source.

This code work's in my dialog, never fails on init, i have not any exception but sometimes i dont see preview.

I'm using it only in this dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are calling the function from the UI thread to access the camera for the API to run reliably?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync.aspx

Comment: Yes. i am sure. I think problem is with disposing MediaSource on leave: 

[code]
                await _mediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync();
                _mediaCapture.Dispose();
                _mediaCapture = null;[/code]